# kendo-upload: inconsistency in FileInfo?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In the [example here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/#toc-events), in `View Source`, in `upload.component.ts` there is the following code:

```
  public imagePreviews: FileInfo[] = [];

(...)

        reader.onload = function (ev) {
          const image = {
            src: ev.target.result,
            uid: file.uid
          };

          that.imagePreviews.unshift(image);
        };
```

If I use it, I get the following error:

`Argument of type '{ src: any; uid: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FileInfo'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ src: any; uid: string; }' but required in type 'FileInfo'.`

If I check [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/FileInfo/), I see that `src` is not an element of `FileInfo` and therefore the error I get makes sense, indeed. However, I don't understand why it works in their web-page and how could I make it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an error, indeed. If you simply change

`imagePreviews: FileInfo[] = [];`

with

`imagePreviews = [];`

it will work without raising any problem.

Even though the properties of `FileInfo` and `const image` don’t match, the properties of `FileInfo` are not used in `image` and therefore the program runs as expected (despite the errors).